# Statistical Intervals - Confidence Intervals

Tags: probability

The problem in the textbook is:

Let $0 \le γ \le α$. Then a $100(1 – α)\%$ CI for $μ$ when $n$ is large is

$$
\left(\bar{x} – zγ\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}, \bar{x} + zα-γ \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}\right)
$$

The choice $γ = α/2$ yields the usual interval derived in Section 7.2; if $γ \ne α/2$, this interval is not symmetric about $\bar{x}$. The width of this interval is $w = s(zγ + zα-γ)/\sqrt{n}$. Show that $w$ is minimized for the choice $γ = α/2$, so that the symmetric interval is the shortest. [Hint: (a) By definition of $zα$, $Φ(zα) = 1 – α$, so that $zα = Φ^{-1}(1 – α)$; (b) the relationship between the derivative of a function $y = f(x)$ and the inverse function $x = f^{-1}(y)$ is $(d/dy)f^{-1} (y) = 1/f’(x)$.]

Please help solve this problem.

I am completely confused on how to work this problem.  I think the issue for me is that there are no numbers or values in the problem.

Comment: I reformatted the math using MathJax/LaTeX markup; please check to see if the text is still good. Also, it would be better to add your thoughts so far about the problem.

Comment: The text looks correct, thanks for reformating.  So far, the only thoughts that I have on the problem is that I should use the hint (a) to substitute into the formula given for w.  But, I am confused on where to go from there.

Comment: Additional thoughts and to prove that z_gamma+z_(alpha-gamma) is minimal when gamma=alpha/2. Take a derivative with respect to gamma: (z_gamma+z_(alpha-gamma))'=(Phi^{-1}(1-gamma)+Phi^{-1}(1-alpha+gamma))'=... and check that this derivative is 0 when gamma=alpha/2.